# Best practice with previous versions / shadow copy (CIFS storage)?

Tags: backup, restore, cifs, volume-shadow-copy

Currently I'm using previous versions (i.e. shadow copies) as backup for a network share.

I need to solve a problem with restoring:

when restoring a file only the owner can use previous versions.Even Domain or Enterprise admins can not restore files or folders

What is the best practices to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with access rights. Note that on Windows even an administrator may be denied access to a file. In these cases the admin must take ownership of the file to access it.

The problem may be that access permissions for the old versions of the file are different from the current version. You can access the old version's permissions on the "Old versions" tab ("Properties" context menu); check that permissions are sufficient. Again, an admin may need to take ownership to access the data.

*Finally a note:* You do realize that shadow copies are not generally considered a backup, don't you? Among other problems, they may be deleted automatically when space runs low, and they do not protect from hardware problems (dead harddrive). Please make sure you have a proper backup as well.

Comment: Shadow copies are used for fast restore. Other backup is made safe on tape.

Comment: @Axxess: Ok, then everything's fine :-). Just wanted to point this out.

Comment: But in my situation the admin user is not allowed to take ownership ?

Comment: @Axxess: On Windows, the admin user is always allowed to take ownership. If that does not work, there is another problem (e.g. file is locked, AV interfering). You'll probably have to experiment a bit to find out what causes the problem.